# Linking new member registrations to a specific site in MSM

Tags: members, multi-site-manager

This question is a parallel to this question

[Making a select-type custom profile field actually *required*](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/3693/making-a-select-type-custom-profile-field-actually-required)

but it seemed correct to separate the two aspects in two different questions.

I am running a pair of sites using MSM and, although I have a separate registration form for each site (i.e. different template, different URL), there is no way of actually linking a newly registered user to the site they registered for - as all new users end up in the same "Pending" list, regardless of which form they filled in.

This is one of the strange features of MSM, where some membership features are site-specific and others are not.

Is there anyway of linking new registrations to the site they have registered for?

I know that I could have them placed automatically into a site-specific member group, but then you lose the ability to activate multiple users while sending an activation email - which you get when using the "Pending" list; something my client wants to keep.

I have tried creating a custom profile input field and placing in the registration form as a hidden input field with its value fixed, but if the field is not configured as visible on the registration form, the system won't write the content in the database; and, if it is visible amongst my custom profile fields and is included in the form as a hidden input field, then it is effectively appearing twice.

Many thanks

Chris

Comment: I'm not certain how this question is different from the prior question. But this one makes me wonder, why 'Member Group' isn't good enough for this situation. Do you understand that, once an individual is activated (moved from Pending) they are properly placed into the default member group for the site (possibly even a more specific group). But basically, if members of site1 are designated to go into the member group 'site-1' then they will do so on activation.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is not a way to link the member to their member site while they are in pending status using EE's native code.

With that said, your approach of using a custom member field is the correct one. **[Your other question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/3693/making-a-select-type-custom-profile-field-actually-required)** will help you figure our how to get this field correctly working in your registration field.